# ForEach to Trim string values in string array

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach

I just wondered why this ForEach doesn't work and leaves the values with trailing whitespace.

```
string days = "Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday";

string[] m_days = days.Split(',');

m_days.ToList().ForEach(d => { d = d.Trim(); } );
```

**I know there are other ways of doing this so i don't need and answer there.**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Because you are not reassigning the trimmed strings.

```
var list = m_days.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToList();
```

> Why `ForEach` doesn't work or if I am using the `ForEach` incorrectly?

`ForEach` is not Linq, it's a method of `List<T>`. What you are doing is basically this:

```
foreach(string day in m_days)
{
    day.Trim();  // you are throwing away the new string returned by String.Trim
}
```

Instead of using LINQ you could also use a `for`-loop instead:

```
for(int i = 0; i < m_days.Length; i++)
{
    m_days[i] = m_days[i].Trim();
}
```

Comment: yeh i want to know why ForEach doesn't work or if I am using the ForEach incorrectly. I know you can use a Select statement...

Comment: @David: Please see my answer for an explanation on why you can't use `ForEach` for this task.

Comment: @David: `ForEach` is not Linq, it's a method of `List<T>`. Edited my answer.

Comment: yeh, ignore that linq tag. means nothing to the question anyway

Answer (score 4):

You need to assign the output of your ForEach to a new variable, like so:

```
var trimmedResult = m_days.Select(d => d.Trim()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

`string.Trim` returns a new string instance. So you have to somehow *use* that new instance.
You are not doing that in your code.
Furthermore, it is not possible with `ForEach`. At first glance, the following could work:

```
m_days.ToList().ForEach(d => { d = d.Trim(); });
```

But that isn't going to help you either, because `d` is not passed by reference, so you are only changing the local parameter that has been passed into your delegate and not the instance stored in the list.

You most likely want this:

```
var result = days.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList();
```

An alternate way without LINQ would look like this:

```
var split = days.Split(',');
for(int i = 0; i < split.Length; ++i)
    split[i] = split[i].Trim();
```

Comment: beat me to the post but this is the best solution imo

Comment: Ok, no need to post further alternatives. I know the alternatives. I think I may have been misunderstanding the use of the ForEach. I just wanted to know why exactly the Foreach doesn't work

Comment: @David: Well, that's explained in my answer in the part after the first code snippet.

Answer (score 3):

Because `String.Trim()` do not modify original string. When you call `ForEach(d => d.Trim())` you create new trimmed string in memory for each item of list, but that string is not assigned anywhere. Thats what you are doing:

```
foreach(string d in list)
{
    d.Trim();
}
```

What you need is

```
m_days = days.Split(',').Select(d => d.Trim()).ToArray();
```